# Setting up Tile Map Service on Apache

Tags: tiles, apache, gdal2tiles

I am trying to set up a tile map service on Apache. I tried following this:
[Setting Up a TMS Tile Map Service on a Web Server](http://www.aubrett.com/InformationTechnology/Geospatial/TMSTileService.aspx) but when I go to load the page it's not loading the images in my /var/www/TMS/1.0.0/ne1 directory returning "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://mysite-name.com/TMS/1.0.0/ne1/2/0/1.png" in the error console.

In the Apache config file:

```
Alias /map/ "/var/www/TMS/1.0.0/ne1/openlayers.html"
<Directory /var/www/TMS>
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

root.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<Services>

  <TileMapService title=" Tile Map Service" version="1.0.0" href="http://mysite-name.com/TMS/1.0.0/service.xml" />

</Services>
```

service.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<TileMapService version="1.0.0" services="http://mysite-name.com/TMS/root.xml">

<TileMaps>

   <TileMap srs="EPSG:4326" title="ne1" profile="geodetic" href="http://mysite-name.com/TMS/1.0.0/ne1/tilemapresource.xml"/>

</TileMaps>

</TileMapService>
```

tilemapresource.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TileMap version="1.0.0" tilemapservice="http://mysite-name.com/TMS/1.0.0/service.xml">
      <Title>test.vrt</Title>
      <Abstract></Abstract>
      <SRS>EPSG:4326</SRS>
      <BoundingBox minx="-125.00000000000000" miny="20.00330020777438" maxx="-54.99858571732217" maxy="50.00000000000000"/>
      <Origin x="-125.00000000000000" y="20.00330020777438"/>
      <TileFormat width="256" height="256" mime-type="image/png" extension="png"/>
      <TileSets profile="geodetic">
        <TileSet href="2" units-per-pixel="0.17578125000000" order="2"/>
        <TileSet href="3" units-per-pixel="0.08789062500000" order="3"/>
        <TileSet href="4" units-per-pixel="0.04394531250000" order="4"/>
        <TileSet href="5" units-per-pixel="0.02197265625000" order="5"/>
        <TileSet href="6" units-per-pixel="0.01098632812500" order="6"/>
        <TileSet href="7" units-per-pixel="0.00549316406250" order="7"/>
        <TileSet href="8" units-per-pixel="0.00274658203125" order="8"/>
      </TileSets>
    </TileMap>
```

openlayers.html:

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS("Weather TMS","http://mysite-name.com/TMS/",
                    {
                         layername: "ne1",
                         type: "png",
                         isBaseLayer: true,
                         getURL:getURL
                    });
                   map.addLayers([layer]);
```

If there are no suggestions to fix this problem, could you point me to something similar to Tile Map Service. I am using gdal2tiles to break up my images into tiles and I have many images that I would like to serve through a tile service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had my configuration messed up

Apache config:

```
Alias /map/ "/var/www/TMS/"
<Directory "/var/www/TMS">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

In open layers.html, I was using http://mysite-name.com/TMS/ (the directory) when I should have been using the alias (map) in the Apache configuration file:

```
 var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS("Weather TMS","http://mysite-name.com/map/",
                    {
                         layername: "ne1",
                         type: "png",
                         isBaseLayer: true,
                         getURL:getURL
                    });
                   map.addLayers([layer]);
```